# Laravel - Sitewide Sidebar

Tags: php, laravel, routes, controller, laravel-middleware

I want to add a sidebar to all of my pages, which will contain content from the database.  Every page on my site will have this side bar added.  I originally decided to create a controller which can provide the content, and then add the sidebar html and an ajax function on my layout template which will request the sidebar data after each page has loaded.  However, I feel like I can make my system more efficient if I can find a way to add the side bar data to all of my controller returns so that I can remove the ajax call.  How does one do this?

Update: I could like to avoid manually adding the data to each of my controller returns if possible. If doing this is necessary, please let me know why.  example:

```
return view('configurationManagement.baselines.bulk_upload')
            ->with("sidebarContent", $sidebarContent)
            ->...
```

Comment: Take a look at View Composers: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/views#view-composers. If `$sidebarContent` is always going to be the same, then you'd define a Composer for your Sidebar View, and you wouldn't need to call `->with('sidebarContent')` _anywhere_. See if you can implement that, and feel free to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75561675/edit) if you run into problems, or post a self answer if you get this working.

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks!  This looks like what I need.  I'll have to read more about it.